# How to auth with Selenium on python in Google account?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried all the options from the stackeoverflow, but none of them helped to solve the problem, how to bypass the detector on the bot?

and is there any other variants? NOT via selenium
and also please explain if "off js-scripts" will help?

my code:

```
url1 = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F"
url2 = "https://colab.research.google.com/..."

from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()

desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, desired_capabilities=desired)


driver.get(url1)
sleep(8)
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId')
email.send_keys("email")

sleep(1)
nextBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
nextBtn.click()

sleep(7)
'''
passwd = driver.find_element('password')
passwd.send_keys("password")

nextBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passwordNext')
nextBtn.click()'''

sleep(400)
```

Please help me.......

Comment: Please describe more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Weboide I want to log in to my Google account in order to manage my project on Google colab